# Grub 2 grub-mkconfig missing

Tags: grub2

I installed grub2 for windows. But I cannot find grub-mkconfig.exe to generate grub.cfg file.I tried to find it in installer directory. But did not find the command. Only there was a file called grub-mkconfig_lib

Comment: I think you'll find it's most likely `grub2-mkconfig` and not `grub-mkconfig`

Comment: The name is not the problem. The problem is it is missing. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: you can try compiling it from source, or you'd have to take a sample grub.cfg and manually create one. AIO Boot's repo on github provides a sample